# Unable to link StepDef with features when using the new io.cucumber package after 4.7.1 Cucumber update

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I've been trying to link my feature files with my stepdefinition files. I have everything linked properly. The thing is Cucumber has been refactored after 4.3.0 and now when I try to use the "Create Step Definition" option in Intellij I end up using the deprecated imports.

The Linkage between the steps and the features works perfectly with them, but when I change the imports manually the steps in the feature file are no longer defined. Even though the "Given", "When", "Then" are no longer deprecated.

So could someone give me some guidelines on what to try to resolve this issue?

I've tried editing the Configuration and adding a Main class of `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` but it still does not work.

Comment: seems like the intellij plugin is yet to be upgraded for latest cucumber version.

Comment: Upvote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, this is exactly the issue. Will wait for the next version of IntelliJ, the stepdefinition of the features will have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem with the IntelliJ Cucumber plugin. It is now fixed in the latest IntelliJ update:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391.